# How to check if any statisfying clause exists in Prolog without backtracking through all different paths?

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut, prolog-setof

Let's say I have the following:

```prolog
parent(alice, charlie).
parent(bob, charlie).
parent(bob, diane).
parent(alice, diane).
parent(bob, eve).
parent(alice, eve).    

% people are siblings of each other if they share a parent 
% and aren't the same person.
sibling(A, B) :-
  parent(X, A),
  parent(X, B),
  B \= A.
```

Now if I ask for the siblings of Diane, I get Charlie and Eve — twice, once through Bob and once through Alice. I only want each once.
I don't think I can use a cut here, as that would prevent backtracking altogether. What I *would* like, is a way to check if *any* exists.

Paraphrasing

```prolog
sibling(A, B) :-
  ∃(parent(X, A), parent(X, B)),
  B \= A.
```

---

I tried several cuts, but none worked.
I tried `findall/3` on `(parent(X, A), parent(X, B))` and checking if the resulting list is non-empty, but that doesn't unify A or B.

---

Using `setof/3` as suggested below works, but I really want to find a way to incorporate it in the definition of `sibling/2`, instead of having to use it in the question. I'd really like to be able to do the following:

```prolog
?- sibling(diane, X).
X = charlie ;
X = eve ;
false.
```

or this

```prolog
?sibling(X, Y).
X = charlie,
Y = diane ;
X = charlie,
Y = eve ;
X = diane,
Y = charlie ;
X = diane,
Y = eve ;
X = eve,
Y = charlie ;
X = eve,
Y = diane ;
false.
```

---

Like I said below, I have a solution for this specific case. What I *would* like, and what I'm setting a bounty for, is a general solution.

Instead of

```prolog
sibling(A, B) :-
  setof(D, X^(parent(X, A), parent(X, D)), Ds),
  member(B, Ds),
  B \= A.
```

I'd like to do

```prolog
sibling(A, B) :-
  exists(X^(parent(X, A), parent(X, B))),
  B \= A.
```

which unifies `A` and `B`.

How do I define `exists/1`?

Comment: I had a very similar case and ended up doing what @false suggested with `setof`. I also did play with a few techniques to avoid putting redundant answers in the results, but they often were more complex than just using `setof`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using cut in Prolog is very delicate. Most cuts are essentially incorrect, but work still in certain situations. You could use a cut here, provided you want exactly one answer. But since you want the entire set, you are out of luck: You need to explore all answers to determine that set.

Fortunately, there is an elegant shortcut (pun intended) for that: `setof/3`. So ask

```
?- setof(t, sibling(diane, S), _).
```

For this usage of `setof/3`, the last argument is of no interest. It is actually `[t]`.

For a general purpose `exists/1`, define

```
exists(XGoal) :- setof(t, XGoal, _).
```

This allows the use of existential quantifiers.

Comment: Yeah, that works. And the first argument is of no interest either. `setof(_, sibling(diane, S), _).` does the trick. I'm still trying to find a way to incorporate it in the definition of sibling, though.

Comment: @SQB: `_`s in setof are often a bug (in the 2nd argument). Yes, it works also with a first argument `_` but here you are exploring some pretty scary limits of `setof/3`. Better keep it some atom. `t` is pretty idiomatic.

Comment: Define `mysibling(X,Y) :- setof(t,sibling(X,Y),_).` There is not much more to it than that. What else were you thinking of?

Comment: Or: `exists(XGoal) :- setof(t,XGoal,_)` Now you can even use quantifiers.

Comment: Yes, that works! I could've sworn that didn't unify, but it does. I must've messed up somewhere. Anyway, bounty earned :)

Comment: I have provided a solution using a cut [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68753360/2326961) giving multiple answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version using only the [cut predicate](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=!/0) `!/0`:

```
person(alice).
person(bob).
person(charlie).
person(diane).
person(eve).
parent(alice, charlie).
parent(bob, charlie).
parent(bob, diane).
parent(alice, diane).
parent(bob, eve).
parent(alice, eve).

sibling(X, Y) :-
  person(X),
  person(Y),
  X \= Y,
  sameparent(X, Y).

sameparent(X, Y) :-
  parent(P, X),
  parent(P, Y),
  !.
```

We do not put the predicate `!/0` in the predicate `sibling/2` to allow backtracking to the goal `sibling(X, Y)` after the first common parent has been found. Instead we put the predicate `!/0` in a new predicate `sameparent/2`. We also add a `person` predicate because the goal `X \= Y` requires its `X` and `Y` to be instantiated. See [this document](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eafsaneh/csc324w13/prolog-cut.pdf) for more information.

A query:

```
?- sibling(diane, Y).
Y = charlie
Y = eve
```

Another query:

```
?- sibling(X, Y).
X = charlie,
Y = diane
X = charlie,
Y = eve
X = diane,
Y = charlie
X = diane,
Y = eve
X = eve,
Y = charlie
X = eve,
Y = diane
```

Comment: I uv'd but actually you've cheated a little  bit here by adding the `person/1` predicate that wasn't there. :) the original Q asks for a solution using only `parent/2` as the fact base. to be compliant, you'd have to define `person` in terms of `parent` too.

Comment: `sameparent(charlie, P), P = diane.`  fails, yet `P = diane, sameparent(charlie, P).` succeeds. Now have these two persons the same parent or not?

Comment: @WillNess Yes I have cheated a bit. Do you know how to define `person/1` in terms of `parent/2`?

Comment: @false You are right, so there does not seem to be a correct program using only cuts.

Comment: @Maggyero I suspect this is equivalent, in essence, to what the question is asking. :) usually using `dif` helps in such cases, to turn operational definitions into the proper declarative ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
parent(alice, charlie).
parent(bob, charlie).
parent(bob, diane).
parent(alice, diane).
parent(bob, eve).
parent(alice, eve).
    
% people are siblings of each other if they share a parent 
% and aren't the same person.
sibling(A, B) :-
  setof(D, X^(parent(X, A), parent(X, D)), Ds),
  member(B, Ds),
  B \= A.
    
?- sibling(X, Y).
X = charlie,
Y = diane ;
X = charlie,
Y = eve ;
X = diane,
Y = charlie ;
X = diane,
Y = eve ;
X = eve,
Y = charlie ;
X = eve,
Y = diane ;
false.
```

---

Now I'm wondering how to extract this to a method `exists/1`, for general use.

Answer (score 1):

So, as seen in the accepted answer, we can run

```
?- setof(P, (parent(P,diane), parent(P,X), X\=diane), _).
```

or

```
?- setof(P, (parent(P,diane), parent(P,X)), _), X\=diane.
```

to get what you want.

Hence we can define a *binary* predicate "exists `A` such that `B` holds":

```
exists(A, B):- setof( A, B, _).
```

and use it as

```
sibling_v1(A, B):- exists( P, (parent(P,A), parent(P,B)) ), B \= A.
```

or as

```
sibling_v2(A, B):- exists( P, (parent(P,A), parent(P,B), B \= A) ).
```

to define the desired predicates.

But it'll still run through *all* the possible paths to find out *all* the possible solutions (just *reporting* each *once*). For how could it be certain to have not missed *some*, otherwise?

```
57 ?- exists( P, (parent(P,diane), parent(P,X), X\=diane)).
X = charlie ;
X = eve.

58 ?- exists( P, (parent(P,diane), parent(P,X), writeln([P,X]), X\=diane)).
[bob,charlie]
[bob,diane]
[bob,eve]
[alice,charlie]
[alice,diane]
[alice,eve]
X = charlie ;
X = eve.

59 ?-
```